# Nuget package with dependency on earlier version of same package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to install a package through nuget, which has the following dependency chain.

Acrobat 11.0.05 => Acrobat 11.0.04 => Acrobat 11.0.0 => Visual C++ 2010 Runtime

The exact error message I get is 
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Acrobat (=11.0.04)'
Circular dependency detected 'Acrobat 11.0.05 => Acrobat 11.0.04'

I'm assuming that it considers these two packages to be the same, although they actually are not. The update to 11.0.05 is meant to be run on a working install of 11.0.04 which must be applied to an 11.0.0 install and must be installed in that order.

I know I could name them like AcrobatUpdate and AcrobatSecondUpdate instead, but that seems like a hack. If I can get this thing to work as intended, I'm certain my employer would prefer that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When authoring NuGet packages, it's encouraged to pack the everything that's at the current state and increment the version number of the package, instead of doing incremental content changes in packages for each version.

Or you could rename the dependent package to have a different ID.